# Select2 not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

The below code works perfectly without calling select2 on the element. It adds all the options in and renders as should.

```
let selectInput = $('<select ' +
    'class="checklist-input" ' +
    'id="' + inputId + '" ' +
    'data-checklist-item-field="' + field + '" ' +
    'data-checklist-item-id="' + itemId + '" ' +
    (disabled ? 'disabled' : '') +
    '>');

$.each(data.summary_input_options, (_, val) => {
    selectInput.append(`<option value="${val.value}">${val.value}</option>`);
});

selectInput.val(value);

return selectInput;
```

However, the second I add a select2 call to the jQuery object things go weird, and the select2 fails to show most of the time, and if it does happen to show up - the second I change the value in the select it goes away again.

`selectInput.val(value).select2();`

It appears select2 is getting called correctly but is not inserting the HTML to render a select, because as you can see below, select2 is correctly inserting it's accessibility tags into the original select:

```
<select class="checklist-input select2-hidden-accessible" id="checklist-summary-52" data-checklist-item-field="summary" data-checklist-item-id="52" data-select2-id="checklist-summary-52" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <option value="Yes" data-select2-id="29">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
</select>
```

If anyone has encountered this issue before or has any ideas please let me know

Comment: add a separate class `select2 ` in <select> . It will work

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui that array is provided by AJAX and is coming down correctly, as you can see by the options are populated in the result HTML

Comment: @freedomn-m That is exactly what the problem is I believe I literally just realised this, thank you very much! :)

Comment: You *might* be able to use an `Adapter` to determine where to render the select2, but seems a bit overkill if adding to the DOM first is an option.  https://select2.org/advanced/adapters-and-decorators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 is expecting the select to already be in the DOM.

Your code (as provided) does not (yet) add it to the DOM, so select2 doesn't know where to add its elements.

You could try to add a wrapper to selectInput and specify the dropdownParent to that wrapper, but it's unlikely to work as select2 will try to find that parent in the DOM to make its changes.

**Solution:** Add the select to the DOM first before changing it to a select2.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the css class i.e **select2**. Please add it.

> You must append the html to DOM first then call the **select2()** function.

```
<select class="checklist-input select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="checklist-summary-52" data-checklist-item-field="summary" data-checklist-item-id="52" data-select2-id="checklist-summary-52" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
   <option value="Yes" data-select2-id="29">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
   <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
</select>

// try with this small change also (optional).
selectInput.val(value);
selectInput.select2();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried this and it is providing the same results. I also tried the small change you described and again I have received the same results.

Comment: check if you are calling `select2.min.css` and `select2.full.min.js` properly? Go to view page source.

Comment: I am using select2 throughout the whole system, all of the other selects work with the exception of this one, I am going to make a change and insert the HTML into the dom before calling the select2 function, as is done for all selects except this one, and see if that makes a difference

Comment: O I see. That's needed first. You have to append the html first and then call the function.